# What are glm's vec1, vec2, vec3, and how/when should I use them?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

What is a `glm::vec2` what are its applications? I cannot find it in the glm reference. I can, however, find vec1. This leads me to think that `vec2` is for 2D, `vec3` is for 3D, etc., but I might be wrong.

Comment: You cannot find it in the glm reference? Sad, because it's there :) [glm::vec3](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00168.html#gaa8ea2429bb3cb41a715258a447f39897) : "3 components vector of floating-point numbers. "

Comment: Drop and JBL: I do know what vectors and matrices are -- I am specifically asking about glm's vec classes, and the differences between vec2, vec3 etc., since I cannot find the reference.

Comment: I just gave you the reference link in my comment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GLM's `vec2` is a utility class representing 2D vector, there are also `vec3`, `vec4` classes available for 3D and 4D respectively.

GLM is also offering matrix classes following same naming conditions `mat2`, `mat3`, `mat4`.

You can multiply a matrix with a matrix or a matrix with a vector using overloaded `*` operator.

For more info on matrixes and vectors in OpenGL you can refer to this tutorial: [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/)

Comment: Usually the `w` component in a `vec4` is an identifier (normals or positions), not a fourth dimension.

Comment: Yes, but when you use vec4 you usually want exactly "w", not 4-th coordinate. Tutorial contains more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the `vec2`/`vec3`/`vec4` typedefs in GLM's `type_vec.hpp`. Have a look in the github repo [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec.hpp#L377). The type aliased by the `typedef` will depend on which `GLM_PRECISION_XXXXXX` macro is active. A `vec2` will though be an alias of a `tvec2` specialisation; for example: `tvec2<float, highp>`. `tvec2` is defined [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec2.hpp) and [here](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec2.inl).